# Unexpected token in JSON when receiving 'application/octet-stream' from API

Tags: angular

My web API is returning a stream as "application/octet-stream". I can see the content in the response and it is not json.

In my angular code, I have

```
   const headers = new HttpHeaders({ responseType: 'blob', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + r.access_token });

        return this.http.get<Blob>(this.getFullUrl(actionUrl), { headers: headers}).pipe(
            catchError(this.onCatch));
```

It is still throwing an error saying

> "Unexpected token  in JSON" Not sure how else to tell it not to
>   expect JSON. I have tried setting "Content-type":
>   "application/octet-stream"

in the http get as well.

Comment: Check the network tab for what headers are present in the request.

Comment: ResponseType should not go in the headers, it should go in the RequestOptions object

Comment: See https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get: open the section with the 15 overloads, look at the second one, and see what you need to pass as option to get an Observable<Blob> as a result. Note that this overload is not a generic method.